# How can I insert an indentation before the first paragraph and to leave other paragraphs without it?

Tags: indentation

I am creating a document in LaTex and my abstract looks like

[image: looks like]

The code part is:

```
\section{Введение}

\textbf{Образцы:} 9 клеточных ...

\textbf{Задача:} Выполнить ...

\textbf{Методы исследования:} Анализ ...
```

As a result I get **Задача** and **Методы исследований** with indentation and **Образцы** without it. How can I insert it when?

*A small update* What if I need the first paragraph to be indented and others to be not?

Comment: The first paragraph after a section etc. is ever indented. All other paragraphs are indented by default. Is this going to be a list? If so, have a ook at https://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=LaTeX/List_Structures&stable=0

Comment: Load package `indentfirst` to get the first paragraph after sectional units indented.

Comment: @samcarter `\indent` has no effect after a section heading

Comment: Yes,  I need a list of paragraphs. I loaded `indentfirst` and it worked the way I need it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for your comment, something new to learn every day!

Comment: By the way, the logarithm in base 2 should be input as `\log_{2}`.

Comment: Okay thank you all guys. One more question: how to make paragraphs without indentations except the first one?